# How can I determine an expected value of a variable that depends on a probability distribution function?

Tags: probability, statistics

> The distribution of downtime $T$ for breakdowns of a system is given by
>
> $$f(t) = (a^2)te^{-at} \text{ for }t > 0$$
>
> where $a$ is a positive constant.
>
> The cost of downtime derived from the distruption resulting from breakdowns rises exponentially with $T$:
>
> $$\text{cost factor} = h(T) = e^{bT}$$
>
> Show that the expected cost factor for downtime is $$\left(\frac{a}{a-b}\right)^2$$, provided that $a > b$.

How can I show this? I know how to calculate the mean of the pdf but how do I combine it with the other function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For any function $g$, the expected value $\mathbb{E}[g(Y)] = \int g(y)f(y)$ where $f(y)$ is the probability density function.

Answer (score 1):

The expected cost factor is:
$$\int_0^{+\infty} h(t) f(t) dt=\int_0^{+\infty} e^{bt} a^2 t e^{-at} dt=a^2 \int_0^{+\infty} t e^{-(a-b)t} dt $$
and (for $a>b$):
$$\int_0^{+\infty} t e^{-(a-b)t} dt=\left(\frac{1}{a-b}\right)^2$$